# Update model according to database changes

Tags: synchronization, consistency, updatemodel

I have an array filled with objects , queried from a database and this array is displayed as a table to the user.

The user wants to delete 1 item so the server receives the request from the client and updates the database accordingly.

**Question** : How should I update the user's view ? 
should I requery the Database again and select everything from it and reasign it to my model or should I do a fast `array.remove(element)` ?

Which one is the preferred method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dealing with a real world application than you should always query the DB for fresh result. Doing this ensures,

1. You have consistency across the application (this approach will work for Add/update too).
2. Data Integrity, which will help you to ensure that DB operation was successful.

So re-query the Database again and select everything from it and reassign it to your model.

Answer (score 1):

You should wait to see if the **db** query (the `delete`) ran correctly and then remove the item from the `array`.

The only reason to do another `select`, is if you want to check for any modifications in the **db**.